# how to get scrollable and zoomable image view of google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to obtain a scrollable image view of google maps. Secondary requirements are-

1. zoom options
2. Being able to put a marker on co-ordinates of my choice.

   Creating a fragment containing only this image view will help me in my app. How can this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: refer this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in zoom controls that Maps API provides. These are disabled by default. You can enable these by calling UiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true)

For the markers, you can use the object Marker. Markers are objects of type Marker, and are added to the map with the GoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions) method. They are designed to be interactive and can be customized via the API.

Below is a sample implementation of adding marker wherein a marker is created at coordinates 10,10 and displays 'Hello world" in info window when the marker is clicked.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hello world"));
}
```

Other helpful links:

Code snippets:    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map
Demos and Sample Code:    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/ (Demos and sample code section)

Comment: Thanks for the great help sir.